# Export Postgres queries to the same excel file

Tags: excel, postgresql

I know I could copy a query to a csv file using:

```
COPY (
 SELECT * FROM my_table
) TO '/tmp/myfile.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t';
```

But I need to export multiple queries to the same csv file, like:

```
COPY (
 (SELECT * FROM my_table) AS tab1
 (SELECT * FROM my_table2) AS tab2
 (SELECT * FROM my_table3) AS tab3
 (SELECT * FROM my_table4) AS tabN
) TO '/tmp/myfile.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t';
```

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: I should have mentioned that they bring out different fields, so i couldn't union them..

Comment: I just edited.. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You can do a union on all the select statements as long as you select the same column types from each, like so.  If cola and colc are not the same type, cast it to the same type.  If you have fewer fields, select a static value such as 0, NULL, or something like that.

```
COPY (
 (SELECT cola, colb FROM my_table1) AS tab1
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT colc, cold FROM my_table2) AS tab2
) TO '/tmp/myfile.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t';
```

Alternatively, you could do the export to 2 files and combine them.  Use your code to export to `/tmp/myfile1.csv` and `/tmp/myfile2.csv`

Then:
`cat /tmp/myfile1.csv /tmp/myfile2.csv >/tmp/combined.csv`

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question.. they are diferent tables.. So I couldn't union them

Comment: See the part after "Alternatively" in my post above, then

Comment: How are the tables different then?

Comment: if you don't have access to the server how are you accessing the files?    Alternatively you can use "\copy" in psql on your local machine, that will let you save the file locally.

Comment: See my edit, write your select statements to specify columns instead of `select *` and make them return the same number and type.  That will work.

Comment: Yeah.. that would work, but it's not what I'm looking for.. I was wondering if I could separate them into tabs...

Comment: what about if i would have access to the server and use your alternative way... could I put them to different tabs?

Comment: No, you cannot specify tabs in a CSV.  CSV is comma separated values, and spreadsheet tabs cannot be represented in a CSV file because CSV has no way to express that.

Comment: You say that would work, but it's not what you're looking for?  It's exactly what you are asking for in your question, so perhaps you should ask for what you want.  Nowhere in your question do you say that you want the data in a spreadsheet with each file in a different tab, all you say is that you want them in one CSV file